# Converting data frame into deeply nested list

Tags: r, purrr, r-whisker

I'm trying to create a data structure that the `whisker` package expects, and I can't seem to figure out how 
create that structure from my data frame. Let's say I have the following data frame:

```
library(dplyr)  

existing_format <- 
  mtcars %>% 
    select(carb, gear, cyl) %>% 
    arrange(carb, gear, cyl) %>% 
    distinct()
```

...I would like to go from `existing_format` to the following desired format (only first two elements of `desired_format` list are shown):

```
desired_format <- list(
  list( 
    carb = "1",
    gear = list(
      list(gear = "3", cyl = list(list(cyl = "4"), list(cyl = "6"))),
      list(gear = "4", cyl = list(list(cyl = "4")))
    )
  ),
  list( 
    carb = "2",
    gear = list(
      list(gear = "3", cyl = list(list(cyl = "8"))),
      list(gear = "4", cyl = list(list(cyl = "4"))),
      list(gear = "5", cyl = list(list(cyl = "4")))
    )
  )
)
```

I've tried things like grouping by `carb` and `gear`, then using `tidyr::nest()` to create a nested df, but nothing is doing. Something tells me that `whisker::iteratelist()` or `whisker::rowSplit()` is the way forward, but I can't figure it out.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: `dflist <- lapply( (existing_format %>% split(., .[,'carb'])), 
                  function(xtbl) xtbl %>% split(., .[,'gear']))`  This may give you a head start.

Comment: that helps, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps more flexible than it needs to be in this case, but you can do a recursive split

```
rsplit<-function(dd) {
  col <- names(dd)[1]
  dat <- dd[[1]]
  xx <- lapply(unique(dat), function(x) {
    z <- setNames(list(x), col)
    if(ncol(dd)>1) {
      z[[names(dd)[2]]] <- rsplit(dd[dat==x,-1, drop=FALSE])
    }
    z
  })
  xx
}

rsplit(existing_format)
```

This will split on all the columns and use the names from the column headers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way, not general for n columns, but it works for 3.

```
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

output <- existing_format                           %>%
    map_df(as.character)                            %>%
    group_by(carb,gear)                             %>%
    summarize_at("cyl",~lst(map(.,~lst(cyl = .x)))) %>%
    mutate(gear = map2(.x = gear,.y = cyl,~lst(gear = .x,cyl = .y))) %>%
    group_by(carb)                                  %>%
    summarize_at("gear",~lst(gear=.))               %$%
    map2(.x = carb,.y = gear,~lst(carb = .x,gear = .y))

identical(output[1:2],desired_format) #TRUE
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. you may be working off of different version of purrr than me, b/c i was getting an error when running your answer. i've edited it to a version that runs for me (though feel free to let me know if u think it should be changed back)