# How to create multi-dimentional arrays in R

Tags: arrays, r

I'm new to R and trying to create a multidimentional array. The array should have the following structure:

```
array -->
  ["game_no"] : 1 
    -> [winner] : True
    -> [state_no] : 1
      -> [state] :
        -> [1] : "x"
        -> [2] : "y"
        -> [..]
      ->[state_no] : ...
["game_no"] : 2, etc.
```

Does R support data structures such as this? How should I approach this?

Comment: it is called a nested list. check [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47802545/converting-data-frame-into-deeply-nested-list) for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R's arrays follow more the mathematical array object of generalized N-dimensional structure (with matrix as a special array of 2-D structure) where **all** elements maintain same types, similar to Python numpy array or Matlab array.

Your suggested object is more akin to PHP, Perl, or Ruby multidimensional arrays (or Python lists/dictionary) which are really hash tables under the hood, and the best counterpart in R will be a named list such as below. Here you can nest lists with named objects all containing different types (character, numeric, logical, etc.). Do note: booleans in R are ALL CAPS.

```
list(game_no = list(winner = TRUE,
                    state_no = list(state = list("x", "y", ...))
                    state_no = list(...)
                   )
     )
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but it looks like the OP wants the `state` to be a sub list of `state_no`

Comment: Possibly, I was more focused on the definition of *array*. But updated accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

@Mattia is close. In `R` the way you would build this structure is with `list`.

```
myList <- list(game_no = list(list(winner = TRUE, 
                                   state_no = list(list(state = c("x", "y")), 
                                                   list(state = c("x2", "y2"))), 
                                   list(winner = FALSE, 
                                        state_no = list(state = c("z", "w"))))))

$game_no
$game_no[[1]]
$game_no[[1]]$winner
[1] TRUE

$game_no[[1]]$state_no
$game_no[[1]]$state_no[[1]]
$game_no[[1]]$state_no[[1]]$state
[1] "x1" "y1"


$game_no[[1]]$state_no[[2]]
$game_no[[1]]$state_no[[2]]$state
[1] "x2" "y2"



$game_no[[1]][[3]]
$game_no[[1]][[3]]$winner
[1] FALSE

$game_no[[1]][[3]]$state_no
$game_no[[1]][[3]]$state_no$state
[1] "z" "w"
```

Answer (score 2):

Since this is an array of arrays, you could build on this solution:

## empty list to start with

```
X <- list()
```

## we get a vector

```
v1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

## add it to the ragged array

```
X <- c(X, list(v1))
```

## get another couple of vectors and add them as well

```
v2 <- c(9, 8, 7, 6)
v3 <- c(2, 4, 6, 8)
X <- c(X, list(v2, v3))
```

## add some more elements to the first vector in X - note double

brackets to access the vector directly

```
X[[1]] <- c(X[[1]], 4, 3, 2, 1)
```

Comment: R does support string indexes. Check this out http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/list/named-list-members

Comment: Sorry @JosephWood, but I had seen a solution without string indexes. I edit my comment